# Google Sheets Query to match any string in a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match

I am attempting a query where I match to any of the items in Column D "Tag" as shown below:

[image]

Currently, I have it to query only from cell D2, but any attempt I have tried to expand that to the entire list in column D have proven futile.

D may not always be the same length, so it is important that the result is not restricted on any particular cells (want D2:D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*An adjustment to your current formula using `textjoin()` should do:*

```js
=query(drafts!A:C,"where A matches '"& textjoin("|",1,D2:D) &"'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with `QUERY` is not trivial, I would recommend using [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

```cpp
=FILTER(drafts!A:C,XMATCH(D:D,drafts!A:A))
```